# SharePoint 2013 Access Services can't add app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, microsoft-access, access-services

I setup Access Services in my Farm with the help of the official Microsoft whitepaper.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30445

The setup worked fine but when I try to add an Access App I get the error "Sorry something went wrong with adding the app".

I can't find any further information in the Log files.

In the EventViewer I get the message "There is no SharePoint Foundation service context" in category Access services.

I am also able to see that when I add the app, the databse is being created but then after a few seconds the database is getting deletet and i get the error message  "Sorry something went wrong with adding the app" on the Sharepoint site.

I hope someone is able to help me!

Thanks for reading and kind regards!

Comment: could you please give the details about the event log error and are you getting any correlation id?

Comment: I've got the same message while attempting to create database.
Anyone?